# Cart Rules Label not showing when using Table Rates

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, shipping, cart-rule, table-rates

I've created the shipping prices using Table Rates.
And I've created a Cart Rule, that when cart total is equal or more than 600, the shipping is free. And I've added a label to the rule, which says "Free Shipping".

Everything works fine! The shipping cost is set to "0", when the total-requirement is met, but the Cart Rule Label isn't showing.

I want it to say "Free Shipping" instead of "Carrier", when the Cart Rules are met.

Is there any work-around for this?

(I've tried activating Free Shipping and setting the minimum amount to 99999999, but then both the "Table Rates" and the "Free Shipping" shippingrules are showing in the cart. And I only want 1 to be shown.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by overwrite some core models.
1. Create custom model and in config.xml rewrite Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method class:

```
<global>
  <models>
    <shipping>
      <rewrite>
        <rate_result_method>SSD_Tools_Model_Rate_Result_Method</rate_result_method>
      </rewrite>
    </shipping>
  </models>
</global>
```

There is SSD_Tools_Model_Rate_Result_Method is my model name, you replace it with your own.
2. Create Method.php file in local/SSD/Tools/Model/Rate/Result and its structure will be:

```
class SSD_Authorizenetcim_Model_Rate_Result_Method extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method
{
    public function getMethodTitle(){
        return ($this->getPrice())?$this->getData('method_title'):Mage::helper('sales')->__('Free Shipping');
    }
}
```

That's all!